# PHP: confused about file paths, includes not working as they should, I guess

Tags: php, model-view-controller, include, filesystems, require

I have the following directory structure:

```
--root
  |--datasource
  |  '--datasource.php
  |
  |--public_html
     |  '--app
     |     |--view
     |     |--model
     |     |--core
     |        '--App.php
     |     |--controler
     |     |--init.php
     |
     |-----css
     |-----js
     |-----index.php
```

My init.php (from the "app" dir.) is included in the index.php and it contains all other important includes for my project:

app/init.php:

```
    require_once '../../datasource/datasource.php'; --> Not working
  //require_once '../datasource/datasource.php'; --> Working
    require_once 'app/core/App.php'; --> Working
    //FUN PART:
    require_once 'core/App.php'; --> Still working, wtf?

    echo getcwd(); //gives: /home/prbh0pr/public_html
```

Question: Why does my '../../datasource/datasource.php' include fail? And more important, why does 'core/App.php not fail?

I try to wrap my head around this, but can't figure out what is happening.

index.php

```
    <?php

      require_once 'app/init.php';

      $app = new App;

    ?>
```

Comment: Try adding `./` in front of the paths. Also check for any `setcwd()` calls.

Comment: first is not working becouse after `../../` you will be behind the root directory (`public_html/../` is `root`, `public_html/../../` is parent of `root`).

Comment: For second, in addition to `setcwd` also check `__autoload` and `spl_autoload_register`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check your path with [get_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php)

The `../../datasource/datasource.php` is failing because your current directory is `public_html` and you're using relative path.

> Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

Found in [documentation about ini.include-path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

The `app/core/App.php` and `core/App.php` are working because

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

Found in documentation about include

The `app/core/App.php` is found in current working directory (`home/prbh0pr/public_html`) and the `core/App.php` is found using calling script's own directory (`~/public_html/app`)